# Promises returns an undefined value

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I'm trying to make a test with jest and promises.

When I try to write in console the result get it from the promise I've got an undefined value

This is my testing code:

```
describe("Search concurrent with promises", () => {
    describe("Test 10: Several searches in DDBB", () => {
        function connection(){
            let ddbb = new PGMappingDDBB();
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let db = ddbb.connect();
                //resolve("Hello World");
                resolve(db);
            });
        }
        test("Test 12: Several searches concurrently", () => {
            connection().then(ddbb => {
                console.log(ddbb);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`ddbb.connect()` is an asynchronous function. The code of connect() is:

```
async connect(){
    this.client = await poolMapping.connect();
}
```

When I try to write the state of the variable `ddbb` I've got that is undefined.

However, If I comment `resolve(db)` and remove the comment of `resolve("Hello World")`, when I write the value of `ddbb` I've got `"Hello World"`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

ddbb.connect() returns a Promise. If I write what returns console.log(ddbb.connect()). I've got:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: Read the docs https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Comment: I have read it, but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: can you show the code for ddbb.connect? To make sure you're returning a promise

Comment: You do not set async anywhere or you do not use the done() method

Comment: check this line: let db = ddbb.connect(); 

probably db is undefined because .connect() is async method

Comment: Your code makes no sense. If the connect method is asynchronous why aren't you awaiting it? What's the point in wrapping something that's already a promise in a new promise? Why don't you handle the promise in your test?

Comment: @Mero Yes, connect() is an async method

Comment: @epascarello resolve(db) should resolve with a Promise. Logging ddbb shouldn't result in undefined. It should at least log "Promise"

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to use Promise.allSettled() and all the parameters are promises.

Comment: What? What parameters? Where's allSettled?

Comment: Test still does not actually test anything. No verification that something ran correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain:

```
async connect(){
    this.client = await poolMapping.connect();
 // NOTE: There is no return value
}
```

```
describe("Search concurrent with promises", () => {
    describe("Test 10: Several searches in DDBB", () => {
        function connection(){
            let ddbb = new PGMappingDDBB();
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let db = ddbb.connect();
            //      ^^ this will be undefined, as connect has no return value
                resolve(db);
            //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Resolving the promise with undefined
            });
        }
        test("Test 12: Several searches concurrently", () => {
            connection().then(ddbb => {
                console.log(ddbb);
              ///           ^^^^ will be undefined
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Additionally, jest is not waiting for the outcome of the promise, and you are not asserting anything in the test, so it will always succeed.

When dealing with promises, if you return the promise from the test, Jest will wait for it.  But you still need to assert on the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your appreciated help and kindness in answering!!!